# left join logic not as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a query that should, I believe, return all email addresses from table 1 regardless.

If I go `SELECT COUNT(email), COUNT(DISTINCT email) contacts.sid208` I get 200,000 and 175000.

With this in mind, by using left joins the count of email from the following query result should be the same no?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(email), COUNT(DISTINCT email)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        co.email,
            env.env_medium,
            CAST(MIN(co.created) AS DATE) AS first_contact,
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN my.my_id = 581 THEN my.data
            END) AS Created,
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data
            END) AS Upgraded
    FROM
        contacts.sid208 co
    LEFT JOIN contacts.my208 my ON co.id = my.eid
    LEFT JOIN contacts.env208 env ON env.eid = co.id
    WHERE
        my_id = 581 OR my_id = 3347
    GROUP BY email) b1
```

But the results here, if I keep things proportionate, are 150000 and 150000.

I expected the results to be 175000.

My understanding of LEFT JOIN was that all records from contacts.sid208 would be maintained, regardless of whether or not they appear in my208 or env208.

Is my understanding flawed here? Hope my query makes sense to folk, if there's any more info I can add to make my question clearer let me know.

Comment: What table has the field, my_id?

Comment: sorry, my208 has the field my_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a left join, move the conditions to the join as well:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(email), COUNT(DISTINCT email)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        co.email,
            env.env_medium,
            CAST(MIN(co.created) AS DATE) AS first_contact,
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN my.my_id = 581 THEN my.data
            END) AS Created,
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data
            END) AS Upgraded
    FROM
        contacts.sid208 co
    LEFT JOIN contacts.my208 my 
        ON co.id = my.eid
        AND (my_id = 581 OR my_id = 3347)
    LEFT JOIN contacts.env208 env ON env.eid = co.id
    GROUP BY email) b1
```

If you don't do so, you will first perform the join, resulting in all rows from sid208, regardless, with `null` values for missing emails. But then the filtering in the where clause kicks in and those records are removed anyway.

When you move all those conditions to the join, you get all rows, and the emails are only joined when they have the matching contact id, and their own id is either 581 or 2247.

Comment: Thank you very much that has solved my problem. It makes sense now that I think about it too. Thanks again